# ioredis ETIMEDOUT from Azure App Service, but works fine locally, IP's added to firewall

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, azure-redis-cache

I have an Azure Redis Cache which I'm currently testing. It is not being used/nothing is connecting to it besides what I'm trying to do now. It is part of the most basic C0 plan.

The issue is, once deployed as part of an Azure App Service it will constantly throw out:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
     at TLSSocket. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/index.js:282:31)
     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
     at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:449:8)
     at ontimeout (timers.js:425:11)
     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
```

All is well and works fine if I run the app locally. I have added both my local IP and the app service's IP to the firewall as well.

My configuration is:

```
 host: this.get('REDIS_HOST'),
      port: 6380,
      password: this.get('REDIS_PRIMARY_KEY'),
      tls: true as any,
      connectTimeout: 1000,
```

and

```
import * as redis from 'ioredis';
redis: redis.Redis;

in constructor: 

this.redis = new redis(this.configService.getRedis());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue on my environment, then I found it seems to be caused by the `connectTimeout` value is too short and shorter than the default value `10000` of `connectTimeout` defined in [`export const DEFAULT_REDIS_OPTIONS: IRedisOptions`](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/98ebeec1acd2067e52169f53e57e989ebbf671ff/lib/redis/RedisOptions.ts#L30) as below.

```
export const DEFAULT_REDIS_OPTIONS: IRedisOptions = {
  // Connection
  port: 6379,
  host: "localhost",
  family: 4,
  connectTimeout: 10000,
  //.....
}
```

If I set the `connectTimeout` value with `1000` or even `100`, I would get the same issue with yours on my environment, as the figure below.

[image]

So please try to remove the `connectTimeout` property and use the default value, or just set a timeout value longer than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

My specific issue was caused by only setting the IP from the 'custom domain' blade in Azure App Service instead of going to 'Properties' and copying the several IP addresses to the cache configuration.

Once I whitelisted all proper IP's everything worked.

I have however encountered the occasional timeout due to the small connectionTimeout configuration set to 1000ms instead of the standard 10000ms.